# 3D path and its projection on walls with cube markers

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

Does anyone know how to do something like this with tikz?:

[image]

I would like to crate practicaly same thing just with one path 1 point thick withou eyes ect... thanks

exaple of path:

0, 0, 0; 
1, 1, 1; 
2, 2, 2; 
3, 3, 3; 
3, 4, 4; 
4, 5, 4; 
5, 6, 5; 
6, 7, 6; 
7, 8, 7; 
8, 9, 8; 
9, 10, 8; 
10, 11, 9; 
11, 12, 10; 
12, 13, 11; 
13, 14, 12; 
14, 14, 13; 
15, 14, 14; 
16, 15, 15; 
16, 16, 16; 
17, 17, 17; 
17, 17, 18; 
17, 17, 19; 
17, 17, 20; 
18, 17, 21; 
19, 17, 22; 
20, 17, 23; 
21, 18, 24; 
22, 19, 24; 
23, 20, 24;
23, 21, 24;
23, 22, 24;
24, 23, 24;
24, 24, 24;

Comment: can you post the data?

Comment: its show case so data can be random. you can generate any path (random.x, random.y, random.z) of course path must lead from one corner diagonally to second corner and all points of path must be connected by corner edge or wall (so there are not any standalone points).

Comment: I can but I don't want to.

Comment: edited. path example added.

Comment: x,y,z dimensions can have different length..so last point is not necessary (x=y=z)...i edited path little bit so matrix would actually be actually cube.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\def\drawcube{%
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \path [fill=gray, draw=white] 
    (\x, \y, 0)     -- (\x+1, \y, 0) -- 
    (\x+1, \y+1, 0) -- (\x, \y+1, 0) -- cycle
    (\x, 0, \z)     -- (\x+1, 0, \z) -- 
    (\x+1, 0, \z+1) -- (\x, 0, \z+1) -- cycle 
    (0, \y,\z)      -- (0, \y+1, \z) -- 
    (0, \y+1, \z+1) -- (0, \y, \z+1) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\path [draw=black]
  (\x, \y, \z)       -- (\x+1, \y, \z) -- 
  (\x+1, \y+1, \z)   -- (\x, \y+1, \z) -- cycle
  (\x, \y, \z+1)     -- (\x+1, \y, \z+1) -- 
  (\x+1, \y+1, \z+1) -- (\x, \y+1, \z+1) -- cycle
  (\x, \y, \z)     -- (\x, \y, \z+1) 
  (\x+1, \y, \z)   -- (\x+1, \y, \z+1)
  (\x+1, \y+1, \z) -- (\x+1, \y+1, \z+1) 
  (\x, \y+1, \z)   -- (\x, \y+1, \z+1);
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{random(1,3)}%
\ifcase\r
  \or\pgfmathsetmacro\x{min(\N,\x+1)}%
  \or\pgfmathsetmacro\y{min(\N,\y+1)}%
  \or\pgfmathsetmacro\z{min(\N,\z+1)}%
\fi%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={very thick, line cap=round, line join=round,scale=0.5}]
\def\N{10}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\foreach \x in {0,...,\N}
  \foreach \y in {0,...,\N}
     \path [fill=gray!20, draw=white] 
       (\x, \y, 0) -- (\x+1, \y, 0) -- (\x+1,\y+1,0) -- (\x, \y+1,0) -- cycle
       [rotate around x=90]
       (\x, \y, 0) -- (\x+1, \y, 0) -- (\x+1,\y+1,0) -- (\x, \y+1,0) -- cycle
       [rotate around x=-90, rotate around y=-90]
       (\x, \y, 0) -- (\x+1, \y, 0) -- (\x+1,\y+1,0) -- (\x, \y+1,0) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\def\x{0}\def\y{0}\def\z{0}
\pgfmathloop
\pgfmathparse{int((\x==\N) && (\y==\N) && (\z==\N))}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
  \drawcube
\else
  \drawcube
\repeatpgfmathloop
\draw [white, ultra thick] 
  (\N+1, \N+1, \N+1) -- (\N+1, 0, \N+1) -- 
  (\N+1, 0, 0) -- (\N+1,\N+1,0) -- cycle -- 
  (0, \N+1, \N+1) -- (0, 0, \N+1) -- (\N+1, 0, \N+1);
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw [gray, ultra thick]
  (0,0,0) -- (\N+1,0,0) (0,0,0) -- (0,\N+1,0) (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\N+1);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]